# Extracting specific column values in pandas DataFrame comparing another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pd frame:

```
   Name  Age  index_col
0  tom    10          1
1  nick   15          2
2  juli   14          3
```

Also, I have the second pd frame like this:

```
   Name  
0  tom      
1  juli
```

Now, I want to extract "**index_col**" information for the **second pd frame** from the **first one**. I mean that output should be [1,3]. The output format is not important. It can be list, numpy array, pd frame, etc.
How can I do this without using loop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try

```
df1.loc[df1.Name.isin(df2.Name),'index_col']
```

Or if the order matter

```
df.iloc[pd.Index(df1.Name).get_indexer(df2.Name)]['index_col']
Out[103]: 
0    1
2    3
Name: index_col, dtype: int64
```